# TFTrainer import error from transformers library

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers

I have been following a tutorial for fine tuning huggingface models. However, I am not able to import the TFTrainer module. Has it been deprecated or is it another issue?

Import statement

```
from transformers import TFDistilBertForSequenceClassification, TFTrainingArguments, TFTrainer
```

Error message

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'TFTrainer' from 'transformers'
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using `TFTrainer` use `Trainer`

Use the following:

```
from transformers import TFDistilBertForSequenceClassification, TFTrainingArguments, Trainer
```